# Send a CLI command to a program through node js

Tags: javascript

Hello I am looking to try and send commands to a program through node js. I am using child processes to exec the jar file. I have trouble sending the commands however

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('java -jar C:\\Users\\19144\\Desktop\\all\\amp1\\Ampera1.jar -full', (e, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
        console.error(e);
        throw e;
    }
    console.log('stdout ', stdout);
    console.log('stderr ', stderr);
});
```

This is the child process being spawn and I wish to send the following command to the jar

```
'sendTransaction 12500000skms5OGjlKm5NJ7fyftdxkma9kUFR3ZxUO4EFw==GgpH9KkC 100 Ampera'
```

is there any way to feasible do this

```
12500000skms5OGjlKm5NJ7fyftdxkma9kUFR3ZxUO4EFw==GgpH9KkC
and 
100
```

are variables